# How to split array in object and create single entries c# javascript?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, object

I created an asp.net mvc Project and return an array of objects.

In javascript i return the array of objects like:

```
var durationPerMinuteArray = result.map(function (item) {
                    return {
                        id: item['hour'] + " Uhr",
                        data: [{
                            name: item['minute'],
                            y: item['minuteavg'],
                            drilldown: item['minute']
                        }]
                    };
                });
```

But like you see, the value of the propertys name: or y: are often arrays. I want to create an own object for each value of these arrays.
It should look like:

Before:

```
Object {id: "10 Uhr", data:[{name: [13, 16, 20], y: [3,2,5], drilldown: [13, 16, 20]}]}
```

The result I want:

```
(0) Object {id: "10 Uhr", data:[{name: 13, y: 3, drilldown: 13}]}
(1) Object {id: "10 Uhr", data:[{name: 16, y: 2, drilldown: 16}]}
(2) Object {id: "10 Uhr", data:[{name: 20, y: 5, drilldown: 20}]}
```

The result raw result i get looks like:

```
(3) […]
​0: {…}
​​avg: 2.5
​​dateOfDay: "04.06.2019"
​​funct: "funct.Web.Account"
​​hour: 9
​​iserror: 1
​​minute: Array [ 16 ]
​​minuteavg: Array [ 2.5 ]
​​<prototype>: Object { … }
​1: Object { avg: 3, iserror: 3, hour: 10, … }
​2: Object { avg: 141.5, iserror: 1, hour: 11, … }
​length: 3
```

With this method i get this result:

```
public List<ChartDataDTO> GetDataForChart(string function)
        {

            var allItems = db.ChartDatas
                .Where(x => x.Function == function)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Timestamp.Date, x.Timestamp.Hour})
                .Select(x => new ChartDataDTO
                {
                    avg = Math.Round(x.Average(y => y.Duration), 2), //Return list<double>
                    iserror = x.Where(b => b.IsError).Count(), //Return list<int>
                    hour = x.First().Timestamp.Hour, //Return list<datetime>
                    dateOfDay = x.First().Timestamp.ToShortDateString(),
                    funct = x.First().Function,
                    minute = x.Select(y=>y.Timestamp.Minute).Distinct(),
                    minuteavg = x.GroupBy(y => y.Timestamp.Minute).Select(y => y.Average(b => b.Duration)),

                })
                .ToList();
            return allItems;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add what your raw result looks like, it might be better to work from there. So what `result` contains

Comment: Also in the result you want, there is no use for data being an array, it can just be an object

Comment: Added the raw result and the method to get this result.

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues with both your C# code as well as your data structures but ignoring that, if you want to convert the result from server to the format you want, you can do the following:

```
result.map(x=>({
id: x.hour+' Uhr',
data:[{ name: x.minute[0], y: x.minuteavg[0], drilldown: x.minute[0]}]
}));
```